# Electron in Linux with VSCode

Tags: node.js, linux, visual-studio-code, electron

node is installed in /usr/bin/node
I've confirmed /usr/bin/env node returns this
For some reason, though, electron can't "see" node when I'm trying to use it with the following launch.json

```
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug Main Process",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
      "windows": {
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
      },
      "args" : ["."],
      "outputCapture": "std"
    }
  ]
}
```

It tells me to change the runTimeExecutable, but if I change that it's not using electron and my app won't launch for that reason, and it doesn't seem like you can add 2 of them. But I looked at the electron file, and it looks like it's supposed to be using /usr/bin/env node to launch, so I don't get... why it isn't launching with the nodejs I can see.. it's just strange.

This is on a Fedora based distro, but I don't think anything is particularly weird about the install

I did confirm /usr/bin is in my $PATH, it would be crazy for it not to be.

I tried running it in konsole using node_modules/.bin/electron index.js and this failed initially I think because I was using an NTFS partition for the git, but I moved it to btrfs and now it's failing instead with an unhandled EACCESS errno -13 for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was resolved by rm -rf node_modules within the directory after I had moved it from NTFS to BTRFS partition and then re-installing electron same as before. So it was just a "NTFS sucks for linux" issue.  I completely forgot that particular drive was NTFS, and didn't know to look out for this.